# How come JavaScript {this} doesn't reference the parent object?

Tags: javascript, oop, this

When making objects I assumed that `this` would return the object's instance - instead it seems it's something else. Why is this?

```
var Obj = { 
    foo : 'value',
    bar : function() { return this.foo; } // Error
    bar : function() { return Obj.foo; }  // Works
}
```

**Update:** I must be missing something because in some cases using `this` inside objects doesn't work. How come this only references the object instance *sometimes*?

Comment: Your code produces a syntax error... you can't put a semi-colon there.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I forgot to validate the sample before I posted it. I wasn't talking about the actual code snippet though - that was just to show the code I'm asking about.

Comment: A function's *this* value is set by how the funcion is called, it is not set by how it is declared or initialised (except where the ES5 *bind* method is used).

Comment: again, produce a code example the fits your *sometimes* case.. and then you might get a meaninful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does.  You have a syntax issue.

Use commas to delimit object members

```
var Obj = { 
    foo : 'value',
    bar : function() { return this.foo; },
}
```

within member functions `this` refers to a reference to the object that the function is called on.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aCYj3/)

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error, that was just sample code. I must be missing something because `this` still doesn't work on some objects.

Comment: well, programming is kind of binary (pun intended), either it works or it doesn't, if you have another example that doesn't work, there is a reason, I'd love to look at it for you, just add it to the question.

Comment: -1 because it's only part of the answer. A function's this keyword is set by the call in a number of ways: as an object method, using *call* and *apply*, using *new*, using ES5 *bind*, using nothing at all (so *this* might be the global object or undefined).

Comment: I qualify my explanation of this by saying ***"within member functions ... "*** , and no, you're correct I didn't produce a research paper on the meaning of `this` in javascript, simply answered **relevant to the question at hand**, there are plenty of resources to dig into the deeper meanings of `this`.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really have member functions though: objects can have properties that reference functions, but even where those function are defined directly in an object literal that created object A (like in the question) you can still call them in a way that sets `this` to object B.

Comment: what are you talking about? a property is a data member that can represent a function? why argue semantics?  ... Are there multiple objects in the question I'm missing??? what is this A or B business? submit your own answer if you have a better solution/explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that terribly, but it's not just semantics: JavaScript functions don't belong to objects. A function doesn't have some inherent link back to one specific "parent" object. What `this` refers to depends entirely on how the function was called. An example related directly to the simple `Obj` definition from the question: what happens if you pass `Obj.bar` as a callback to some other function and call it from that other function?

Comment: `bar` is name-spaced within `Obj`, therefore membership.  And I'm not sure where in my answer i mentioned anything about "parent" objects or inheritance, and to quote my answer exactly... "`this` refers to a reference to the object that the function is called on." I did not say that `this` refers to a reference to the object **that it belongs to**, which is what it seems like you read.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But regarding the sentence you quote, why then did you start that sentence "within member functions", which to me would naturally mean the sentence should be read as talking about the object that membership applies to. I think we would be in agreement if you were to simply delete those three words (not to imply you want or need my agreement), because really it is "within any function, member or not".

Answer (score 2):

Within a JavaScript function `this` is set depending on how the function was called.

With your example `Obj`, assuming you correct the syntax error and use commas between properties:

```
var Obj = {
  foo : 'value', // needs comma, not semicolon
  bar : function() { return this.foo; }
}
```

If you use the "dot" syntax on `Obj` to call the `bar` function then `this` will be automatically set to `Obj`:

```
Obj.bar(); // this will be Obj
```

That's an easy way to ensure `this` ends up set the way you want. But if you call the function in some other way `this` could be set to something else:

```
var nonObjBar = Obj.bar; // get a reference to the function
nonObjBar(); // this will (probably) be `window`, but depends if
             // in strict mode or inside some other function, etc

var Obj2 = { foo: "other foo" };
Obj.bar.call(Obj2); // the .call() method sets this to Obj2
                    // so bar will return Obj2's foo, "other foo"
```

That last example uses the `.call()` method on `Obj.bar` to invoke the function in a way that allows you to set `this` to anything you like (strict versus non-strict mode affects the way this works for some cases).

It might seem strange if you're coming from languages like Java, but JavaScript functions don't belong to any given object. This behaviour is pretty well defined and on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the semi-colon after 'value', this seems to work:

```
var Obj = { 
    foo : 'value',
    bar : function() { return this.foo; } // Error
};

alert(Obj.bar());   // alerts 'value'
```

See working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UFPFf/.

When you call a method on an object, the javascript engine sets the `this` pointer to point to the object for the duration of the method call.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a semicolon after `foo`.

Actually when you call `Obj.bar` you *will* have *this* referring to `Obj`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/AAkbR/

```
var Obj = { 
    foo : 'value',
    bar : function () { return this.foo; }
};

alert(Obj.bar() === Obj.foo);
```

Alerts true.